# Code calls for a file to be Downloaded+Dialog Box but Only Dialog Box Shows

Tags: c#

I called for the following file to be downloaded in C#, and the Dialog Box Shows saying that the file is download, so when I go to check the folder, the file is not downloaded!

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    string url = @"http://dc451.4shared.com/download/eWW2ICvX/Alexville.zip?tsid=20130402-163358-7222b14a";
    // Create an instance of WebClient
    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    // Hookup DownloadFileCompleted Event
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

    // Start the download and copy the file to c:\temp
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Medieval Silver Edition");
}

void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("File downloaded");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given it a filename.

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url),
           @"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Medieval Silver Edition\Alexville.zip");
```

Comment: I changed it to MedievalSilverPC.zip and I got the following error `The name 'MedievalSilverPC' does not exist in the current method.`

Comment: @Shaharyar - I haven't tried downloading the file itself. Is there an error message?

Comment: @AlexPotter - I just looked at the URL. You're not downloading the file directly, you're linking to a file-hosting site.